# Select more columns with MAX function in SQLCE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Need to find max value of id, and by this value I need to read value of others column. But it is influenced by another column type.
I used this sql command:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table WHERE type = 1)"
```

ID column is bigint type, and type is nchar. I tried use it with type = '1' too, but same problem.
Error is after "id = " section

Thanks for reply

EDIT:

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand();
if (LocalType == '1') { com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT req_id FROM Requisition WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Requisition WHERE type = 1)", con); }
else if (LocalType == '2') { com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT req_id FROM Requisition WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(b.id) FROM Requisition AS b WHERE b.type <> 1)", con); }

using (com)
{
   SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: I suppose that you real table name is not Table right?

Comment: @MartinSmith : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = SELECT ]

Comment: @Steve : No, whole code is show in edit section, table name is Requisition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using `top`.  If this is your real code, then you need to "escape" the word "table" because it is a reserved word:

```
select top 1 t.*
from [table] t
where type = '1'
order by id desc
```

Comment: It change the position of error after "top " section, same with select * from table limit
I edit original post with whole code

Comment: What version of CE are you using? Could it be really, really old?

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table AS a 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(b.id) FROM Table AS b WHERE b.type = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while on google, find that SQLCE in version 3.5 support SELECT TOP expression, but with difference with formating. It must be write with brackets

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM MyTable
```